# Save content on change jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to save the content of the textarea. I tried onkeyup, it is working properly but it is very heavy and some performance issue and onchange and onpropertychange is not working for me. Can anyone suggest some alternative.

```js
function setMsgSession(){
  
  var newMsg = $('#newComposeMessage').val();
  alert(newMsg);
 }
```

```html
<h:inputTextarea id="newComposeMessage" pt:placeholder="Message" pt:maxlength="29000" rows="10" queryDelay="750" minQueryLength="4" onpropertychange="setMsgSession()" >
```

Comment: you can always use setTimer function if you want to continuously save your text data .. give it after every 10 to 20 seconds.

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto I guess you mean `setInterval` but it would be worst. What OP needs is to post the logic used to save data because obviously his performance issue comes from here.

Comment: add fiddle link ..... stack fiddle is not working

Comment: @A.Wolff YES! but setInterveal would be better than onchange or keyup that OP is using. Other than that yes there can be other better ways to do it!

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto The best would be to use `input` event but not supported by older browsers. In this case, the workaround could be to use `$('#newComposeMessage').on('change keyup paste cut mouseup', setMsgSession);` with logic to check if value has changed and debouncing it to avoid mutliple calls. But again, how OP is saving data? Using ajax request, persistent storage client side or what???

Comment: would not be better to use https://api.jquery.com/blur/ ?

Comment: @biancamihai I guess OP wants to save data on the fly, not once changed but otherwise yes it would be better

Comment: @A.Wolff  $('#newComposeMessage').on('change keyup paste cut mouseup', setMsgSession); worked for me but I am more concern about the performance.